# Associahedron, but with swaps

Tags: combinatorics, monoidal-categories, associativity, rewriting-systems

The [associahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associahedron) has edges of the form $a(bc)\rightarrow (ab)c.$ But I also want to include the possibility of swapping adjacent entries by doing operations like $a(bc) \rightarrow a(cb).$ I was wondering if there was some type of combinatorial structure that could help me. My main goal is to find an algorithm that can use these kinds of moves to swap around the $i$th and $j$th entries of some starting structure. For example, I could swap the first and third entries by doing $(ab)c \rightarrow (ba)c \rightarrow b(ac) \rightarrow b(ca) \rightarrow (bc)a \rightarrow (cb)a.$

It would be great to know any references or algorithms I should look at. My interest in this problem comes from thinking about symmetric monoidal categories. I suppose it relates to the permutahedron as well.

Comment: There are some "permuto-associahedra" lurking around the literature (e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.08658 ), although I'm not sure if they are all the same and if they are related to what you want.